# Constant hdd write but iotop shows nothing

Tags: memory, disk-usage, disk, monitoring

The disk activity monitor widget in KDE (Debian) shows constant HDD write around 12 MiB/s, when I run `iotop`, there is nothing that would be constantly using HDD. When I run `atop`, at first `PAG` is red and blinking but after about 3 seconds disappears, when i run `free -h`, I get:

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7Gi       2.2Gi       3.0Gi       1.1Gi       2.5Gi       4.2Gi
Swap:          7.9Gi       0.0Ki       7.9Gi
```

Any idea what can be causing this or how to find out?

Also, i tried to clear the cache, it cleared to 1.5 Gi but after less than 5 minutes it was back to 2.5 Gi as shown above. Also i am thinking that Debian is using quite a lot of memory given that only firefox with the stackexchange window is open.

Comment: Please try `htop`.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov `htop` shows no hdd activity. It might be a bug in the activity monitor HDD activity, now it is showin disk write access 80MiB/s...  When I restart the computer, it is quiet and sometimes it appears after a while... But I just want to make sure that there is no malicious activity going on.

Comment: I've no clue to be honest. I've thought about swapping in/out but according to your output your swap isn't used at all. Another idea could be dirty buffers flushing but the requires copying tons of data. Please try using `sudo fatrace`.